# How to label counties in Mapserver?

Tags: wms, mapserver

I'm fairly new to Mapserver and I was able to get US County boundaries to plot. Is there a way to get the County Name to plot in the center of the county? I've searched around and couldn't find any examples of doing this. Perhaps theres a better alternative that I haven't thought of. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what you have tried.  Using the POSITION property of the LABEL obj, you should be able to place the label in the center of the poly using a value of "cc".  The center of a polygon can be a dodgy concept when you have funny shaped polys.  The center could actually fall outside of the poly bounds.

Anyway, I would try this as the first, simple approach.

```
LABEL
    COLOR  150 150 150
    FONT "sans"
    TYPE truetype
    SIZE 6
    POSITION cc
END
```